# AWS s3 file is not loading Angular ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

Tags: angular, laravel, amazon-s3, ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

We are loading S3 Pdf file in ngx-extended-pdf-viewer (Angular). But it shows the requested domain does not have an access control header Issue.

Notes:

1. Files Uploads from PHP laravel backend
2. We set access control origin header for this domain on https://selvamanidevsaas.selvamani.app But the same issue again

**Errors**

**UnknownErrorException {message: 'Failed to fetch', name: 'UnknownErrorException', details: 'TypeError: Failed to fetch'}
details: "TypeError: Failed to fetch"
message: "Failed to fetch"
name: "UnknownErrorException"**

**Access to fetch at 'https://s3bucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/work_permit/work_permit_1657881550.pdf' from origin 'https://selvamanidevsaas.selvamani.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled**

Comment: The link is offline, so I guess you've solved the issue. Can you share your insight with us?

Comment: The PDF viewer does support S3, so I suppose it was really a CORS issue. I suppose you need to add https://s3bucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com to your access control header. For debugging, you can simply use "*" to check if there's a fundamental problem.